# Change img source on select change in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to change the img i show depending on the value of a select. The state value changes correctly and so does the src value, but it wont find the img.

The code:

```
<img src={"../imgs/".concat(this.state.selectedSceneID)} alt="Scene"/>
```

Basically the value of each select option is the name of the img, which are located in a folder call imgs on level above the react code.

Comment: Do you see image when the app starts?

Answer (score 0):

If your image source is in your state just use back ticks to build your path it out

```
<img src={`../imgs/${this.state.selectedSceneID}`} alt="Scene"/>
```

Comment: The outcome is exactly the same as his code. But its a nicer syntax, I'll give you that.